# Is it possible to use/forward certificate information from key credentials to a bearer token (Azure AD)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, client-certificates

I have a scenario where I have to let external systems have access to one of our internal API's.

The security team want the externals to use client certificates as the preferred authentication method, so that basically leaves us two options:

- Use direct client certificate authentication. It will give us the most control, but that will leave all the certificate handling and validation in our hands, and I'd rather not do that if I have a choice. Besides - direct client certification auth does not play well with our existing authentication methods on that API. If you turn on client certificates on the App Service, you will require a certificate on every request (and most requests on that API use cookies)
- Add key credentials to the Azure AD app. We'd rather not give access directly to the app the API is registered on, so we register a *OUR-APP-EXTERNAL* and set up a trust relationship between the two. So the client authenticates with a certificate to the "external app", gets a bearer token and use that on our API. I'd prefer to use this solution, and it seems to play nicely with everything else.

So far so good - but I'm worrying about scaling this. We have to separate the external clients somehow (each client will in effect be different systems in different companies). One strategy is to create one AD-app per external system (*OUR-APP-EXTERNAL-SYSTEM-A*), but it seems cumbersome and somewhat spammy. One quick and easy solution would be to add some metadata from the client's authentication certificate (where we could just set what system this cert is issued to during creation), and add that to the bearer token.

Is this possible? Or are there other ways to handle "multi tenant" external clients?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider an option of using Azure API Management for your scenario. API Management provides the capability to secure access to APIs (i.e., client to API Management) using client certificates. Currently, you can check the thumbprint of a client certificate against a desired value. You can also check the thumbprint against existing certificates uploaded to API Management.

Follow this guide - [How to secure APIs using client certificate authentication in API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients)

Also you can create multiple Azure AD Application for different clients and provide provide required roles to each of these Azure AD application to Azure AD Application registered to secure Internal API.

Follow this guide for this approach - [Protect an API by using OAuth 2.0 with Azure Active Directory and API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad)